# Unwanted change of depth of cut

Tags: table-saw, cutting

I have a Jet 10" 708325 table saw.

I set the depth of cut, but the blade lowers itself after a couple of cuts. I do not see anything in the manual addressing any adjustments.

Comment: Does the height adjustment wheel have a knob you can turn to lock it in place?

Comment: 708325 appears to be the part number for an **[extension table](http://www.toolorbit.com/Jet/Jet-708325.html)**. You might want to edit the question with the model name/number of the saw itself - or just post a photo.

Comment: Do you find this happening when you've raised the blade to its final position, or when you've lowered the blade to the final position? Given that you've got a good saw, I'm assuming it's the latter, and you're experiencing a form of backlash.